# Install PyQt4 for Python 3.4

Tags: python, qt

I need to install PyQt4 for Python 3.4. I found that when I try

```
 sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt4
```

I am prompted by terminal that python3.2 will be installed( which I assume will try to install python3.2 for python3-pyqt4). I need to install pyqt4 for python3.4 as one of the package requires python3.4.

Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python 3.4.2 is the Python3 version used in jessie.

If you are using wheezy I suggest you upgrade to jessie.

If you are using something else you should include that information in your question.